"Users may see the unverified app screen" when adding scopes in the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK app configuraion
I'm trying to publish a Google Sheets add-on privately. After enabling the Google Workplace Marketplace SDK, I went to the APP CONFIGURATION tab, and started adding the narrowest scopes that the add-on needs. However, several scopes I try adding resulthttps://dandv.me/terms in this error, which at the moment has zero Google hits:
"Users may see the unverified app screen"

Below is a screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

Clicking SAVE DRAFT leads to this error:


have you check that the scopes in your screenshots provided are included in the verified/code?

@LimeHusky: if you mean in appsscript.json, yes, those scopes were included. In the meantime I managed to avoid these errors by apparently filling in the "Store listing" section first, but I'm not clear on the exact cause.

This question is similar to: Setting OAuth scopes for Google Sheets add-on correctly. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm having the same issue too right now when publishing my workspace add-on. This is definitely something new from Google. Please let me know if you have found a workaround

@imLightSpeed same here, It won't let me save it as a draft, and I just want to test my app, but I can't move forward because of this error
